# Visual Studio Team Viewer Deleting Branch Error

Tags: git, visual-studio

I have a very unusual problem. I cannot find any solution. It seems im stuck with a branch I cannot get rid of. Its directory is C:\Users\GaddMaster which is my user directory. This folder contains loads of valuables folders, files and programs. I considered it but realized it may be catastrophic result and all my programs and stuff might vanish.

[image: Image of Team Viewer]

The problem lies when I go to changes, it starts loading all this folder which has everything under the sun, not related what so ever to my project. I think I made a mistake by accident making my username folder a git repo and I cannot simple delete it now

I simple need to push my project to Git Hub so it can be shared. I have been messing for the day but cannot figure it out. Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: I am not sure you have used the right terminology. A 'branch' is not the same as a directory in the filesystem. I think what is being shown is that you have two different repositories. Each repository matches a directory and can track files within that directory structure.

Comment: Your problem is not very clear... But it seems that you created a git repository in the wrong directory. If that is really your problem (verify to be sure because there will be no undo!), just delete the '.git' folder which contains all the git data that make a folder, a git repository...

Comment: Yes your right. I did delete everything from that folder GIT related. But this issue still remains. I cannot get rid of user/gaddmaster from Visual studio.